# Как сделать поле в классе указателем на поле другого класса в c++?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно создать два класса - Автор и Книга. Автор содержит поля фамилия, год рождения и пол.
Класс книга содержит поля название, тираж и автор. Поле автор должно быть указателем на фамилию автора из первого класса. Также нужно сделать публичные геттеры для всех полей. Как мне реализовать указатель, чтобы можно было и геттер сделать и конструктором пользоваться?

Comment: Бессмысленно. Делайте просто указатель на автора, а не на его отдельную фамилию. А автор может содержать указатель на фамилию - мало ли Алексеев Толстых было :)

Comment: Сначала пишите классы так, как умеете, потом преставьте их вместе с вопросом.  Тогда кто нибудь вам и поможет

Comment: Что значит "как мне реализовать"? Вы в своем вопросе фактически сами детально по шагам описали, как вам это реализовать. Это довольно странная реализация, как уже написали в комментариях выше, но если уж вам хочется именно такую - то вперед, реализовывайте. Именно так, как вы написали. В чем проблема?

Comment: Я не знаю как именно сделать поле указателем и как его использовать в конструкторе. Это и спрашиваю.